# range and len statement

Tags: python

I was watching how to plot histogram using python and coming across this statement and I am not sure what it means or how it works.

```
population_ages = [22,55,62,45,21,22,34,42,42,4,99,102,110,120,121,122,130,111,115,112,80,75,65,54,44,43,42,48]

ids = [x for x in range(len(population_ages))]
```

I am not sure how this statement works. I have tried watching videos on how `len` and `range` work but still unsure of how it applies to this statement.

```
ids = [..... range(len(population_ages)]
```

Comment: Note that the `[x for x in ...]` "wrapper" is entirely superfluous is Python 2 and could be replaced with a simple `list(...)` in Python 3 (or just leave the `range` generator as is, depending on what you need it for). In other words, this is probably not very pythonic code.

Answer (score 2):

Let's see:

`population_ages` is the list with all the records.

`len(population_ages)` returns the length of the list. The list `population_ages` has 28 elements, therefore `len(population_ages)` returns 28.

`range(len(population_ages))`, which in this case is `range(28)`, returns `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27]`. That's a list that contains all the possible indexes that you can use to access population_ages (you can evaluate `population_ages[0]`, `population_ages[1]`, ..., `population_ages[27]`; but from 28 and onwards, it will raise and `IndexError`).

`[x for x in range(len(population_ages))]` generates a list, in which each element is each element in `range(len(population_ages))`. This step isn't changing anything, the result still is `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27]`.

That's what's being saved as ids. I wouldn't know how your code uses it later, but that's step by step what that line is doing.

Answer (score 2):

Other answers already cover the basics.

I would like to add that the list comprehension in

```
ids = [x for x in range(len(population_ages))]
```

is a specialization of

```
[x for x in iterable]
```

which isn't really useful because

- it produces `x`, untransformed from the iterable
- it produces something no matter what.

list comprehension is more useful in cases like this:

```
[f(x) for x in iterable if condition(x)]
```

If you *really* want a list out of this, it's even better & faster to create it by passing the iterable through the `list` object:

```
list(range(len(population_ages)))
```

(in python 2, `range(len(population_ages))` is even enough since it directly returns a `list`, but your code isn't portable to python 3 if you really need a subscriptable object.)

Also note that manipulating indexes is often a source of errors. Python has a lot of ways *not* to use indexes (unlike languages like C). A few examples:

- it can iterate on the values themselves
- it can iterate on the indexes+values using `enumerate(iterable)`
- iterables of comparable sizes can be processed in parallel using `zip` or `itertools.zip_longest`
- there are built-in dictionaries

so think hard before using indices. There are probably better ways.

Answer (score 1):

`range(start_number, end_number)` creates a range of value from start_number to end_number so in your case, since the length of population_ages is 28, you'll have values that are `0,1,2...27`

`[x for x in ...]` simply gives you each value within a list. For example [x for x in 'Hello'] will make a list equal to `['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']`. `x` can be named anything.

Comment: The end is `end_number-1`, so it goes to `27`.

Answer (score 1):

It's called a list comprehension, and

```
ids = [x for x in range(len(population_ages))]
```

is the same as

```
ids = []
for x in range(len(population_ages)):
    ids.append(x)
```

Being able to spell it using only one line of code can often help readability.

In this case you'll often see people using `i` as the name of the variable, as in:

```
for i in range(len(mylist)):
```

since `i` will be an integer getting the legal indexes into `mylist`, i.e. the half-open interval [0..len(mylist)> meaning the first time `i` will get the value zero `0` and the last time it will get the length of the list - 1.

Comment: also `ids = list(range(len(population_ages))` avoids the comprehension.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre or just `ids = range(len(population_ages))`, but neither of those are pedagogically preparing you for `enumerate(population_ages)`..

Comment: yes, `range(len(x))` isn't very pythonic, unless you really want the indices and not the data. But that probably means that your data model has an issue.

Answer (score 1):

In your example:
`len(population_ages)`: computes the length of the list `population_ages`.

`for x in range(len(population_ages)`: when you do a cycle like `for x in range(number)` you're indicating that the cycle will range from 1 to the `number`. In this case it will go from 1 to the length of your list which is 28.

In the expression `[x for x in range(number))]` the first x is taking the values that result from the evaluation of the loop, in your case it is going to be 1,2,3.....25.

If you wanted for example to show the same values of your list you should put something like this:

```
ids = [x for x in population_ages)]
```

For more information about these topics you could read:

[len_documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len), [python-list-comprehensions](http://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/)

I hope this help you